# guava - Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst method suddenly not working

Tags: guava, multiset

I'm using guava Multiset library using their maven dependency version 18.0.

I had a following code that used to work fine until a few weeks ago:

```
ImmutableMultiset<String> entryList = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(weightedDocs);
```

which returns a sorted list of a given multiset. 
But suddenly my IDE shows that the method doesn't exist, and woudln't compile. I checked their code in github, but the static method seems to be still alive... what would be a problem??

Answer (score 1):

The method `Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(Multiset<E>)` appeared in Guava 11.0. I'm quite sure that you have somewhere an older version of Guava (maybe even `Google Collections` that is used instead of the version 18.0 that you want to use.

So double-check your dependencies and their dependencies. An older version of Guava is present somewhere and is interfering with yours.